# How to draw multiple circles within circle like target and get touch event of particular circle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to draw target view like this-[image]

And get touch event of a particular circle. 
e.g If user touch between circle 7 then fill black color of circles up to circles 7.

Currently I have two ways to implement this functionality: 
1) Take 10 UIImageView and put on each other and touch of an image view change the colors of image view's according to conditions.

2) Take UIView and draw 20 color gradient (10 for black border line and 10 for white spaces) and save frame of each gradient. After that get user's touch area then change color according to that.

I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not have a single image, and calculate the radius based on the touch point - all you need to know is the centre position.

Instead of radius, what you really need is an index from 0 to 11 for your bands - if they are equal thickness, you can do that in a single calculation - take the integer part of (11 * radius / radiusFull)

If the bulls-eye is a different size, you may need to add some more code.

Either way, you should be able to do it all with a single image - generated on the fly, or simply loaded - and a bit of simple maths.

Comment: Thanks Russell...:) Its sound good but I am looking more answers may be someone have more better solution.